# .ToUniversalTime(), why it works this way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, utc

I noticed this strange issue regarding .ToUniversalTime(), but I can't figure out why.

If I do

```
 DateTime currentServerTime = System.DateTime.Now;
 DateTime currentUTCServerTime = currentServerTime.ToUniversalTime();

 log.Debug("Current server time :" + currentServerTime);
 log.Debug("Current Server UTC Time is :" + currentUTCServerTime);
```

**Result**

```
  Current server time :2/18/2014 2:09:23 PM
  Current Server UTC Time is :2/18/2014 7:09:23 PM
```

**5 hours apart.**

Given the server is located on U.S East Coast, with -5 offset. That's correct.

Now if I do

```
String dateTimeString = "7/10/2013";
DateTime baseLined = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeString);
DateTime convertedUTCTime = baseLined.ToUniversalTime();

log.Debug(dateTimeString + " is :"+baseLined);
log.Debug(dateTimeString + " UTC time is :" + convertedUTCTime);
```

**Result**

```
7/10/2013 is : 7/10/2013 12:00:00 AM
7/10/2013 UTC time is: 7/10/2013 4:00:00 AM
```

**4 hours apart.**

Why one result shows 5 hours difference and another shows 4????

Please help.

=== Edit ====

Thanks to Jon and Usr. Now I understand .ToUniversalTime() will take DST of the server into consideration and adjust the UTC according to the DateTime object it attaches to.

So I'm still trying to wrap my head around it for this situation.

In my database, 7/10/2013 is a due date and was recorded as "7/10/2013 4:00:00 AM" (Since during that time, it was during daylight saving, offset -4).

Now it's in Feburary 2014, DST is not in effect, offset is now -5. But because of this, when I adjust user's timezone offset -5 to "7/10/2013 4:00:00 AM", it becomes 7/09/2013 instead of 7/10/2013.

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: "Given the server is located on U.S East Coast, with -5 offset. That's correct." - What do you think the offset is on the July 10th?

Comment: @Jon, wow, okay. That explains it a lot. So that means ToUniversalTime() will take the daylight saving offset of the server into consideration as well? I didn't know that!!!

Comment: Yes, it will convert the local time into a universal time. It would be pretty useless if it didn't observe DST, to be honest.

Comment: Jon. Thanks a lot. It makes sense, though now I'm perplexed to a situation.  Could you take a look at my "Edit" in the original post and see how do I resolve this situation". Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "when I adjust user's timezone offset"? It would really help if you'd post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. I'd also suggest using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library instead of `DateTime`, but that's a different matter :)

Comment: @Jon, I posted a new question regarding this. Could you take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864346/how-to-convert-a-date-to-utc-properly-and-then-convert-it-back

Comment: Joe's answer there looks good to me. Aside from my normal comment of "Just use Noda Time" of course :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of [daylight savings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). Local time is as it appears on your clock. UTC is continuous without gaps, without ambiguous points in time.

Comment: Thanks usr. I had a wrong understanding of ToUniversalTime() for strange reasons, looks like it takes the daylight saving of where the server is into consideration as well. 

In that case, how do I tell if a time has or  has not been adjusted by daylight saving?

Comment: @Liming that is a new question which I cannot answer.